# Saga Orchestration with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, saga, orchestration

Do we need to use anyone framework like eventuate, camunda, etc. for implementing Orchestration-based SAGA microservices in spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventuate framework to setup a Orchestration-based Saga.
You will need to add Orchestra-tor dependency to your orchestra-tor, and participant  dependencies to all the participant micro-services.
You will also need to run Eventuate CDC tram service, which enables the Transctional messaging services along with the DB.

Try this link and join the slack channel, Mr Cris himself will answer to your issues. Mostly in few hours or a day.

https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas-examples-customers-and-orders

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I have practically explained all the steps the person need to do to setup the eventuate architecture, link is a mere example.

Comment: can you create simple examples to understand?